# What do I wrap in `act` for state changes that are triggered by time and using modern fake timers

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have small hook that I wrote to avoid re-rendering when the component is unmounted.

```
  it("should work and not rerender and unmount later", () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers('modern');

    function MyComponent() {
      const [foo, setFoo] = useStateIfMounted("bar");

      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          await delay(5000);
          setFoo("brin");
        })();
      }, [])
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          await delay(10000);
          setFoo("BAZ");
        })();
      }, [])

      return (<div data-testid="test">{foo}</div>);
    }

    const { getByTestId, queryByTestId, unmount } = render(<MyComponent />)
    expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("bar");
    act(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(4999));
    expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("bar");
    // the following triggers a state change
    // and I get   Warning: An update to MyComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    act(()=>jest.advanceTimersByTime(1));
    // expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("brin");
    // unmount();
    // act(()=>jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000));
    // expect(queryByTestId("test")).toBeFalsy()
  })
```

I get

> Warning: An update to MyComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

at the point where I would expect it to have a state change but I already wrapped it in `act`

```
    act(()=>jest.advanceTimersByTime(1));
```

Comment: The documentation specifies that the rendering needs to happen inside an `act` as well, did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have to sprinkle async/awaits everywhere in order to get it to not appear and to actually make the test work

```js
  it("should work and not rerender and unmount later", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers('modern');

    const renderCallback = jest.fn();
    function MyComponent() {
      const [foo, setFoo] = useStateIfMounted("bar");

      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          await delay(5000);
          setFoo("brin");
        })();
      }, [])
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          await delay(10000);
          setFoo("BAZ");
        })();
      }, [])

      renderCallback();
      return (<div data-testid="test">{foo}</div>);
    }

    const { getByTestId, queryByTestId, unmount } = render(<MyComponent />)
    expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("bar");
    expect(renderCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    await act(async () => jest.advanceTimersByTime(4999));
    expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("bar");
    expect(renderCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    await act(async () => jest.advanceTimersByTime(3));
    expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("brin");
    expect(renderCallback).toBeCalledTimes(2)
    unmount();
    await act(async () => jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000));
    expect(queryByTestId("test")).toBeFalsy()
    expect(renderCallback).toBeCalledTimes(2)

  })
```